# creating and calling stored procedure, passing values into stored procedure from python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

i am a novice at python and sql so i have encounterd some issue while trying to create a stored procedure and passing values to it.

i have looked through few questions here.Of what i could understand i used the ODBC format and it works for procedures not requiring anything to be passed. The query is simple. it takes in 2 parameters route_no and month. the query then count the number of trios taken by a bus per date for that month on that route.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
conn=pyodbc.connect('''Driver={SQL Server};'''
                       '''Server=ABY;'''
                       '''Database=testing;'''
                       '''Trusted_Connection=yes;''')

cursor=conn.cursor()     
proc3="""CREATE PROCEDURE TRIPS_PER_DAY @ROUTENO NVARCHAR(30),@MONTH NVARCHAR(30)
         AS
         BEGIN
         SELECT [ON DATE],SUM(DISTINCT([TRIP NO])) AS SUM_TRIPS
         FROM testing.dbo.sheet1$
         WHERE [ROUTE NO#]=@ROUTENO AND MONTH([ON DATE])=@MONTH
         GROUP BY [ON DATE]
         END"""

drop_proc3="""IF EXIST(SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE TYPE='P' AND NAME='TRIPS_PER_DAY') DROP PROCEDURE TRIPS_PER_DAY"""
call_proc3="""{CALL testing.dbo.TRIPS_PER_DAY(?)(?)}"""
cursor.execute(drop_proc3)
cursor.execute(proc3)
values=('16','11-11-2017')
dff=pd.read_sql(call_proc3,conn,params=(values,))
print(dff)
```

this is the error i am getting:

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '{CALL testing.dbo.PASS_PER_STOP(?)(?)}': ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation (0) (SQLPrepare)')

i am not sure if the method i am using is right or if there is a syntax error.
I am also not sure how to pass values and return results from the procedure using python. Any help?. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: First, it might be that you can only run DML, not DDL statements via ODBC. Secondly, the error code is something that you get when there is no ODBC error code for the SQL server actual error.  So as first stop I would suggest you check mssql server error log. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-error-messages/sqlstate-odbc-error-codes?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: yes!, thank you its a syntax error. Would you let me know how to rectify it?

Comment: probably call the Procedure without the brackets:
"""{CALL testing.dbo.TRIPS_PER_DAY ?, ?}"""
and better with param names:
"""{CALL testing.dbo.TRIPS_PER_DAY @RouteNo=?, @Month=?}"""

Comment: @Ebis thank you .this did work out.